# What is the correct phraseology to request a climb?

Tags: phraseology

If you'd like to request a climb to a higher flight level while cruising, which do you think is a more proper way to request it:

1. Request to climb FL350
2. Request climb FL350

I know they have zero difference in meaning between them, but I'm curious which one might sound more natural or professional in the EPTA test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that “Request climb FL350” is better.

I never use the word “to” in altitude requests as it can be confused with “”two” as in “request climb to seven thousand” (request climb two seven thousand)

If you get in the habit of using “to” with flight levels, you will probably use it in a baro altitude request as well.

I also leave out “climb” and just say “request FL350”. But, when ATC says “climb FL350”, I will read back “climb FL350”.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go wrong with "XXX requests (or requesting) climb FL350". In practice you'll hear a number of ways of saying it, some more conversational than others, depending on how busy the comm freq is.

Also, if you are calling in from out of the blue looking for a significant change in your clearance like that, it's good etiquette to give Center a heads up by saying "Soandso Center, XXXX with a request", then follow up when the controller answers.

Comment: I never use the word “to” in altitude requests as it can be confused with “”two” as in “request climb to seven thousand” (request climb two seven thousand).

Comment: For a baro altitude request yes, but sticking the word "to" in a flight level request, which I tended to do without really thinking about it, doesn't have the same confusion problem as that, but your point is well taken and I edited my post.